# storing MediaObject on ionic storage.set

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-storage

I was trying to save a Media Object on ionic storage but it said this: 
error while saving media object in storage.set

[image]

how can i save media object  from storage.set and get it from storage.get?
and this.audioFile = this.media.create(track.src)
here is the code i wrote:

```
 this.audioFile = this.media.create(track.src) 
 this.trackstoreddata = {
  dataPlaying:this.playing,
  tracks: this.musicApiService.bmusic,
  selectedtrack:this.selectedTrack,
  trackselected: this.trackSelected,
  audiofile: this.audioFile
  }

this.storage.set("trackStoredData",this.trackstoreddata);
```

Comment: Can you show your `code`?

Comment: i edited the question with the code. please check

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: i have edited with the code. please check

Answer (score 0):

The [Ionic Storage docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) mention

> Storage is an easy way to store key/value pairs and JSON objects

So, if what you are trying to store is not a JSON object (like audio or an image), ionic storage will fail.

As an alternative, you can use [Ionic Native File](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) to read/write files onto a device.

Comment: I will try native file.